# Execution plan of query from profiler

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, profiler

I use SQL profiler to know how Entity Framework convert LINQ expression to sql use database. When query is 'heavy' then I try to optimalize it by examine execution plan.

Profiler (I use Profiler Express) give my query in this format

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], (... rest od query ... )
',@p__linq__0=N'test@mypage.com'
```

To see execution plan I have to convert (copy, paste code wrrr) to this format

```
DELARE @p__linq__0 NVARCHAR(100) =N'test@mypage.com'
SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], (... rest od query ... )
```

It is boring ,irritating etc. Does someony know page or somethig which do it for me? Or I can just set it in options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable "Show Actual Execution Plan" and run the query.